# "WiFi adapter doesn't have valid IP configuration" - Please, help! urgent

Tags: wireless-networking, ip, ipconfig

Although connected to the Wi-Fi, the access to the Internet is limited (none). I have tried everything people suggest on the forums. I'm on Windows 8 (Lenovo Yoga notebook)
when typing `ipconfig` it looks like this:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . . . : fe80::e1e4:1d69:5de0:346f%3
Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address . . : 169.254.52.111
Subnet Mask . . . . .. . . . .: 255.255.0.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . :
(Yes, the Suffix and Gateway are blank)
```

Please, help. It is very urgent.

I tried to reset the wifi adapter, reset the ip protocol (somehow) through the cmd window. I installed updates for the Intel wifi adapter. tried to set the IP configurations manually several times... The only thing I haven't tried is reseting the modems as it is a school wifi. And yes, between it I restarted my computer at least six times. So far absolutely unsuccessful.

Update: So it looks like the problem is with the server not sending me DNS and transmitting the configuration properly.
How do I solve it without reseting it or asking the staff - I'm at school and nobody from tech will be here until Monday. Which will be too late for me

Comment: Can you define what exactly "everything people suggest on the forums" entails? It would be helpful to know what you have tried so we know where to start.

Comment: sure. I tried to reset the wifi adapter, reset the ip protocol (somehow) through the cmd window. I installed updates for the Intel wifi adapter. tried to set the IP configurations manually several times...

Comment: basically the only thing I haven't tried was reseting the modem. because it is a school wifi

Comment: it happened to me here once before. but after shutting down and starting the computer again it was ok. not this time. i restarted at least six times the past few hours

Comment: Thanks for the update. It's commonly accepted as best practice here on Stack Exchange that you add more context to your original question with any pertinent updates, including what you have already (unsuccessfully) tried. Please ensure you edit your question and include that information to save others from having to dig through a comment thread.

Comment: Do you know if this Wifi network that you're trying to connect to can issue a valid DHCP lease? Are you able to successfully connect to the Internet on this network with another device, like a smartphone for instance?

Comment: I can connect on a pc. don't have a smartphone... but everybody uses it so I guess it normally works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are showing above is the result of your PC not receiving IP address from a DHCP server. Your IP above 169.254.52.111 is a self assigned IP.

If you are on a home network you could try resetting your router/modem. In many cases that will fix the situation above.

If you are in a hotel/office you will need to talk to the stuff/admin to verify their DHCP server is running.

Comment: sorry!!!! I wanted to give you thumbs up! not down

Comment: it's getting to me

Comment: anyway. thanks for the answer. I'm at school so it's a public network. and sadly the stuff is not going to be here until monday. when it is too late

Comment: isn't there some other way to find out the configuration and manually put it in?